# Why new created index is not available at Discover or Create index pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I create a new index in Kibana for Elasticsearch.

DevTools/Console:

```
PUT test42
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "text" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Than I check all indices:

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

and get a list like that:

health    status    index  ...
yellow    open      test 
yellow    open      test42
green     open      .kibana_1
yellow    open      test_index2
yellow    open      logging-190409
yellow    open      time_series_double_values

When I look at Kibana / Discover **I can't see test42**:

[image: screen shot]

**Why the new index is not available?**

My goal is to create a index pattern for logging as described here: [Logging with ElasticSearch, Kibana, ASP.NET Core and Docker](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/logging-with-elasticsearch-kibana-asp-net-core-and-docker)

Answer (score 5):

The content of the `test42` index will be visible when you select the `test*` index pattern in the Discover view.

If you want a dedicated index pattern for `test42`, then you need to create a new index pattern in "Management > Index Patterns"

Remember: an index in ES != an index pattern in Kibana, the latter can regroup many ES indices using a named pattern

Comment: Thanks for the note about "index in ES != an index pattern in Kibana". When I go to _Kibana/Managment/Create index pattern_ and I type _test42_ into the field, the _Next step_ -button is still deactivate. So I cant create the index pattern. Could it be that I don't have the permissions for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I had to create first a file. Then the index is shown.

```
PUT test42/_doc/1
{
  "properties": {
    "timestamp": "4/9/2019 1:22:18 PM",
    "message" : "initial message",
    "file": "no file",
    "linenumber" : "0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to refresh the browser after successfully creating an index to view it.

once refreshed you should be able to view the index when trying to search via the search option or under index management tab in Kibana